# why set environment variables in scripts?

Tags: bash

I see many add `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/` to their bash script. 
Can someone tell me why this is necessary and what will happen if I don't do it? 
JAVA_HOME is already set in my .bashrc. Why should I specify this again in my script?

Thanks for any help to this newbee...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you may be starting a new shell #!/bin/sh may be your first line of the script.  Check if you are starting bash in the first line of script.

Comment: I am doing that. So my settings in .bashrc wont be remembered by this new shell?

Comment: what is your first line? #!/bin/bash?